# What does Google Webmaster Tools' URL errors measure?

Tags: google-search-console

When I look at the graphs of URL errors for a particular site, is the number in a given day the actual number of errors at that point in time, e.g. is it a snapshot of the number of reported errors or is it the number of errors found on that given day?

Comment: It is the current errors to date. If it found 1 on Monday, 3 on Tuesday but zero on Wednesday then it should read 4 on Wednesday,

Comment: Sometimes I see the graph trend downwards, does that mean some of the previously reported errors must have been resolved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Simon-Hayter noted in his comment, the number of errors reported is a running aggregate/cumulative tally for the site.

It may sometimes spike/jump if the crawlers try to check the site during webserver downtime/maintenance.  Likewise, if you see it trend downwards, it may have detected certain errors as self-corrected.

Possible self-correction measures include:

- Crawling an updated xml sitemap and realizing some urls can be
  delisted.
- 301 redirects having been setup/added for defunct url
  aliases/retired pages.
- site had blocking (usually 3rd party) javascript when initially crawled, but now loads and prevents bots from indexing.

Check out the [Google Search Console Crawl Errors Report (websites) page](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35120?hl=en) for more info about the types of errors reported and manual steps to flag/notify Google that errors have been corrected.